# typescript asking for template literal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using typescript, and is complaining when concatenating a string,

```
  const content = senderDisplay + ', '+ moment(timestamp).format('YY/MM/DD')+' at ' + moment(timestamp).format('h:mm A');
```

> [tslint] Use a template literal instead of concatenating with a string
>   literal. (prefer-template)

What is the template literal to fix this? cheers

Comment: [MDN: Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). They're an alternate string literal, using ticks rather than quotes, and allow for embedding expressions.

Comment: tslint checks for style, you can look up the rules like [`prefer-template`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/prefer-template/) and you can see what is going on...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see the [template literals in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and these are the prefered style in ES6.

In your case it would become the following:

```
const content = `${senderDisplay}, ${moment(timestamp).format('YY/MM/DD')} at ${moment(timestamp).format('h:mm A')}`;
```

Important differences:

- Starts and ends with a backtick
- Supports multiline strings
- Expressions are interpolated with `${expression}`

Answer (score 4):

```
const content = `${senderDisplay}, ${moment(timestamp).format('YY/MM/DD')} at ${moment(timestamp).format('h:mm A')};`
```

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals! They're awesome once you get the hang of it, string interpolation is much more readable than concatenating stuff together.

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks and `${...}`.

```
 const content = `${senderDisplay}, ${moment(timestamp).format('YY/MM/DD')} at  ${moment(timestamp).format('h:mm A')}`;
```